# FBX file did not support Simple Deform Modifier?

Tags: animation, unity, .fbx

I try to create the bending animation and then add it to Unity but it did not work. The final FBX file has no animation.
I wonder that is FBX file does not support the Simple Deform or not. If not, would you mind giving me some instructions to create the bending animation and then import it to Unity?.

I already searched around but can not fix this problem.
I used blender 2.83LTS and unity editor 20.3.31f.

Thanks.

Comment: No, the FBX file doesn't support the _Simple Deform_ modifier (I guess that's what you're talking about?), like most file formats don't support Blender modifiers. The modifiers are Blender-specific tools which are not the same in other programs. You could go to the modifier and choose "Apply as Shape Key", but beware: the frame you're on and the amount of bending there will be the one that's saved as the maximum effect of the shape key. So if you animate bending from 0° on frame #1 to 90° on frame #20, then the shape key will only have 90° at value 1 when you apply the modifier on frame #20.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, "Apply as Shape Key" looks good, I will try with it.

Comment: Just be aware that a shape key animation moves the vertices from their base position to the shape position in a linear movement, so the shortest path from start to end position. If you have a bending animation where you have a curved motion this will look different. Example: [bending vs. shape key](https://pasteall.org/pic/fd861e0d045d40d5bf816f9a193403bb)